# Can't get data from localhost:8081 (expressjs API), I've tried vue-resource and axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js

I am learning VueJS and wanted to make a project. So I've to get data from ExpressJS server/API. I've tried vue-resource and axios. both of them returned status code 0.

I think my API is not responding correctly to HTTP requests.

What should I concentrate on while building API.

P/S: Sorry, can't upload any code, because I'm using different computer.

Comment: `because I'm using different computer.` then go to the other computer. We will still be there until you arrive :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it with

`res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type, \Authorization');`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. However, you mention this:

> I think my API is not responding correctly to HTTP requests.

This may be the case and that would mean that your Express server is not running as expected. The causes I could think of for this are:

1. You are not listening on port 8081, but rather on other port and you
   have not noticed this. If you used Express-generator, the default
   port is 3000.
2. You are not calling the correct route from the front-end. Make sure
       that you are trying to access the correct url. For example you may
       have done the routing as follows:

   > localhost:8081/api/foo

   and later be calling:

   > localhost:8081/foo

   expecting to get a correct answer...

I would recommend to debug your server. Check the logs!
I really doubt your problem has to do with your front-end framework.